# Scheme: Find the frequency of an element in a vector

Tags: vector, scheme, iteration, racket, frequency

I'm new in Scheme. I want to get the number of occurence of a number in a vector.

I'm using this function on vectors whose 0th index is 0.

N is just the length of the vector - 1.

(I'm using this function as part of another function ... that's why I'm setting these requirements.)

This is what I got so far in DrRacket:

```
(define (frequency? test-num solutions N)
  (do 
    ((count 1 (+ count 1)) 
     (result 0 (if (equal? (vector-ref solutions count) test-num) (add1 result) result)))
    ((<= count N) result)))

(define v (vector 0 3 2 4 5 2))

(frequency? 2 v 5) ; got 0 instead of 2
```

I checked that "result" gets changed to 1 on the 2nd index but somehow reverts back to 0 afterwards.

Is there any better way to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jens' answer is of course completely correct. You also ask whether there's another better way to write this code, and indeed I believe there is. I would probably write this code like this:

```
#lang racket

(define (frequency? test-num solutions)
  (for/sum ([value (in-vector solutions)])
    (if (equal? value test-num) 1 0)))

(define v (vector 0 3 2 4 5 2))

(frequency? 2 v) ; got 0 instead of 2
```

Note that there's no need to pass the length. There are of course many other ways to write it, including just `(length (filter (lambda (x) (equal? x test-num)) solutions)`, but while that might be shorter, I think the one above is more readable.

In general, I think I speak for a reasonably large fraction of Racketeers when I say that `do` is rarely the nicest way to express a program.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, is to change `(<= count N)` to `(> count N)`.

```
(define (frequency? test-num solutions N)
  (do ([count  1 (+ count 1)]
       [result 0 (if (equal? (vector-ref solutions count) test-num)
                     (add1 result)
                     result)])
    [(> count N) 
     (display count) (newline)
     result]))
```

If you insert a (display count) before returning result, you
can see what with count.